# Prerendering React Components With React Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have a simple React component that is currently rendering correctly on the client. I am trying to have it render on the server. To test this I am switching off the JavaScript in Chrome and loading the page.

My component looks like this:

```
window.TestComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return React.DOM.h1({className: 'TestComponent'},
        'Test Component')
  }
});
```

The entrypoint looks like this:

```
<%= react_component 'TestComponent', {prerender: true} %>
```

At the moment, the page loads without error and contains the following:

```
<div data-react-class="TestComponent" data-react-props="{'prerender': true}"></div>
```

It seems that Rails is parsing the erb, but fails to render the component it references.

I have included The Ruby Racer in my Gemfile and have verified it is working by printing out some calculations to the DOM.

According to the React Rails docs on server-side rendering there are three requirements:

**Requirement 1**

> react-rails must load your code. By convention, it uses components.js,
>   which was created by the install task. This file must include your
>   components and their dependencies (eg, Underscore.js).

My component is located in: app/assets/javascripts/components/test_component.js.erb and should be loaded by the JavaScript in components.js:

```
//= require_tree ./components
```

**Requirement 2**

> Your components must be accessible in the global scope. If you are
>   using .js.jsx.coffee files then the wrapper function needs to be taken
>   into account:

I am using plain JavaScript

**Requirement 3**

> Your code can't reference document. Prerender processes don't have
>   access to document, so jQuery and some other libs won't work in this
>   environment :(

I don't reference document.

**What might I be doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<%= react_component 'TestComponent', {}, {prerender: true} %>
```

The first hash is empty - it's empty paras for the react component.

The second hash is options for react-rails, that's where you say 'prerender: true'.